# How can I create a single line editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I want to replace an input field with an ACE editor.

So what I need to do is to disable return/enter keys and remove all commands that create a nested popup (like find/replace).

I've tried to set the maxLines option on the renderer, but this did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The demo on ace has something similar see
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.9/demo/kitchen-sink/layout.js#L103
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.9/demo/kitchen-sink/demo.js#L210-L221
It sets maxLines, removes some commands and adds override for enter